# Como usar um Webhook em Angular?

Tags: angularjs, http, http-request, webhook

Nunca utilizei nenhuma comunicação com Webhook, no momento estou recebendo comunicação da **API Moip Assinaturas**, quando um novo assinante é registrado eu recebo um JSON com o evento e as informações do assinante que foi criado.

Estou utilizando o **RequestBin** para fazer os testes, já que não consigo receber Webhook no meu servidor local (localhost:4200).

Gostaria de saber como faço para ouvir uma comunicação Webhook e ver qual evento foi enviado pela API Moip Assinaturas quando alguma ação é executada na API.

Por exemplo quando uma fatura é criada, é disparado o evento *INVOICE.CREATED*.
https://dev.moip.com.br/v1.5/reference#exemplo-de-webhook-de-faturas-invoices

Gostaria de controlar com um serviço quando recebo um Webhook e notificar o usuário da ação que ele realizou, seja um pagamento realizado etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um *WebHook* funciona como um *[callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))* - neste caso uma URL que é chamada pelo servidor remoto.

> Gostaria de saber como faço para ouvir uma comunicação Webhook e ver qual evento foi enviado pela API Moip Assinaturas quando alguma ação é executada na API.

Você precisa expor sua máquina de desenvolvimento para a internet, de maneira que requisições externas cheguem à sua máquina.

A maneira para implementar isso dependerá da sua topologia de rede local - via [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) ou adicionando sua máquina ao domínio [DMZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)), por exemplo.

Comment: estou usando ngrok para teste e recebendo um JSON via POST da API, porém preciso pegar esse JSON toda vez que receber um POST da API, como faço para ficar ouvindo se recebo um POST em Angular 5?

Comment: @LuizCardoso sendo o back-end o alvo da chamada de callback eu diria que você pode precisa informar o frontend. Duas possibilidades: polling ou stream (websocket ou similares).